# Show there is an unbounded continuous function on a closed nonempty subset of a metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $X$ be a metric space. Let $E \subset X$ be not closed and nonempty. Show that there is a continuous real-valued function on $E$ that is not bounded.

The only function that I know of that is continuous on $E$ is the distance function for some fixed point in $E$. That is, the function $d_p:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $q \mapsto d(p,q)$.

Comment: Initital hint: $d_p$ is also continuous on $E$ if $p$ is a point that is not in $E$.

Comment: Ok, so, let $p \in S\setminus E$. We have $S \setminus E$ is not open, since $E$ is not closed.

Comment: Second hint: if $E$ is not closed, then $E$ has a limit point which is not in $E$.

Comment: Ok, so, if $p$ is a limit point of $E$ which is not in $E$, then every $\epsilon$-ball centered at $p$ intersects with $E$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p$ be a limit point of $E$ which is not in $E$.  Consider the function $1/d_p$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $E$ is not closed. Therefore, $closure(E) \ne E$. Thus, there exists a limit point $x_0$ of $E$ in $closure(E) \setminus E$. By the definition of limit point, all neighborhoods of $x_0$ intersect $E$. Therefore, for any $r > 0$, there exists some $x \in E$ such that $x \in Ball(x_0, r)$. Thus, if we let $f(x) = 1/d(x, x_0)$, then $f$ is unbounded because we can make $r$ arbitrarily small.